# I'm making a bot to automate buying gun primer and I need it to click a dropdown button for the amount of rounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, bots

One of my dad's friends wants me to make a bot that automates buying gun primer because they are always sold out. I have a script with some ammunition as a test (because its actually in stock), but as I try and figure out how to click the dropdown, the terminal always spits out this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid type: null, expected a string at line 1 column 12
```

For reference, I am using Python 3.9 with Selenium 3.141.0 and this is my code:

```
#imports funcs from selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#chooses your browser

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#gets your store
url = driver.get("https://www.midwayusa.com/product/2090655809")

#opens the website
driver.get(url)

#makes variables for html elements
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productSelectorContainer"]/div[1]/button')

#le button click has arrived
button.click()
```

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown? Make that clear in your posted code.

Comment: driver.get(url) is odd since you already use driver.get (actual url) before it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue. You have these two lines

```
#gets your store
url = driver.get("https://www.midwayusa.com/product/2090655809")

#opens the website
driver.get(url)
```

`driver.get()` doesn't return anything so `null` gets stored into `url`. Then on the next line you are navigating to `null`. These lines are actually redundant and looks like you misunderstood how to use them. You only need the first line, with some corrections.

I removed the redundant line, corrected the other, and made some adjustments to some of your comments to make them more accurate.

```
#imports funcs from selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#launches the browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#navigates to your store website
driver.get("https://www.midwayusa.com/product/2090655809")

#stores the button in a variable
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productSelectorContainer"]/div[1]/button')

#le button click has arrived
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Faults:

```
url = driver.get("https://www.midwayusa.com/product/2090655809")
```

is not a valid just use driver.get('url')

You need to click the consent otherwise it overlap all the clicks otherwise.

Here's an example of clicking the 50 quantity of the item at hand and then proceeding.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get("https://www.midwayusa.com/product/2090655809")
driver.maximize_window()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#cookie-consent-btn"))).click() 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#productSelectorContainer > div.product-filter.original-selector > button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#Quantity > ol > li:nth-child(1) > button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.big-primary-button.add-to-cart-button"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs

[image]